# JavaScript login before fetch JSON

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm have this login form on `/json`

```
            <form action="/json" method="post">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="ps" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" value="ENTER" id="ab">
            </form>
```

and i need to enter password and click on submit button before i fetch JSON with this code

```
fetch('/json')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML = out.Proxies.join("\n");
    })
    .catch(err => { throw err; });
```

how to do this?

i can do it from chrome console with

```
document.getElementById('ps').value = 'test'
document.getElementById('ab').click()
```

Comment: What about binding submit event on the form element and pass the fetching as a callback to the event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send `POST` with password

```
fetch('/json', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams("password=test")
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].innerHTML = out.Proxies.join("\n");
    })
    .catch(err => { throw err; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `onsubmit` value, like

```
        <form action="/json" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('ps').value = 'test';">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="ps" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" value="ENTER" id="ab">
        </form>
```

If you have something more complex, then it is more elegant to define a `function` which is to run before `submit`, like

```
function beforeSubmit() {
    //Your code here
}
```

and call that in the `onsubmit`:

```
        <form action="/json" method="post" onsubmit="beforeSubmit();">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="ps" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="submit" value="ENTER" id="ab">
        </form>
```